# Stuck at Building Android App using Bazel

Tags: bazel

I am following the guide to build android using Bazel (https://bazel.build/start/android-app) but unfortunately I am stuck at excuting build command.

I am running in windows 10, tried Bazel versions 6.0 & 7.0.0 .exe downloaded from Baze's GitHub page

Please assist.

Below please find the error log

C:\Bazel>bazel build //src/main:app

INFO: Analyzed target //src/main:app (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).

INFO: Found 1 target...

ERROR: C:/bazel/src/main/java/com/example/bazel/BUILD:5:16: Desugaring src/main/java/com/example/bazel/libgreeter_activity.jar for Android failed: Worker process did not return a WorkResponse:

---8<---8<--- Start of log, file at C:/users/eric/_bazel_eric/4yp365mj/bazel-workers/worker-15-Desugar.log ---8<---8<---

LAUNCHER ERROR: Cannot launch process: "bash.exe" -c "C:\\Users\\Eric\\_bazel_eric\\4yp365mj\\execroot\\**main**\\bazel-out\\x64_windows-opt-exec-2B5CBBC6\\bin\\external\\bazel_tools\\tools\\android\\desugar_java8 --persistent_worker"

Reason: (error: 2): The system cannot find the file specified.

---8<---8<--- End of log ---8<---8<---

Target //src/main:app failed to build

Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.

INFO: Elapsed time: 1.123s, Critical Path: 0.27s

INFO: 3 processes: 3 internal.

FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfull

Comment: Do you have a `bash` installed? Some rules require `bash` on Windows. You could install https://www.msys2.org/.

Comment: I have installed msys2.org but build still fails

Comment: Similar issue what you are referencing https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/11618